# How to initialize HashSet variable during debug in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to initialize `Set<String>` variable during the debug session in eclipse. So I right-click on the variable to change and in "Change Object Value" window type the following expression:

```
new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b"}));
```

Eclipse returns the following error:

```
HashSet cannot be resolved to a type
Arrays cannot be resolved
```

Is there any way to initialize a collection during debug session in eclipse ?

Comment: Note that you don't need the explicit array creation: `Arrays.asList("a", "b")` works the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a class that is not imported (no corresponding `import` statement in the current file), then you can use these classes by their fully qualified names:

```
new java.util.HashSet<String>(java.util.Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a", "b"}));
```

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible solution would be to use the `Display` view in `Debug Perspective` of Eclipse :

Enter that :

```
yourSet = new java.util.HashSet<String>();
yourSet.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
```

Then, select these lines, right-click and choose `execute` option.

Here an example with a screenshot :

[image: Display View in Eclipse]

The advantage of `Display` view is you can call  as many operations as you want on variables you are debugging (`add()`, `remove()` on your `Set` for example). 
It is not possible to perform the same thing with `Variables` view where `Change Object Value` option allows only to assign the specified value to a variable.

Other advantage of `Display` view : you write the code to execute in a natural way as you write your code in a class.
After having discovered `Display` view, I didn't use `Change Object Value` option any longer.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
Set<String> yourSet =   new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
```

And your eclipse errors, you need to import Java.Util and Collection classes. Right click anywhere on your class and click on "source" >> "organize imports".